# Cannot find protocol declaration for NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on ios5 and have used `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` in my application which really works fine for me. But I run the same project on ios 4.3 I am getting the error :

**Cannot find protocol declaration for NSURLConnectionDataDelegate**

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` we should use `NSURLProtocolClient`.

Comment: NSURLProtocolClient is a different protocol, I guess you should rather be using NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

This was introduced in iOS 5.  Several protocols that were informal in iOS 4 related to NSURLConnection became formalized in iOS 5.  In this case, if you need to support iOS 4 - you will need to do this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem..dont know if my solution is 100% correct but i tried weak linking some frameworks..and then run again.. or removing and relinking them again.